# Star Trek TOS-TNG crossover novel

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, star-trek-eu

I have been searching for the title of a TOS-TNG crossover novel for some time. I believe it was published in the early 1990s, as I do not remember Voyager or DS9 being on TV. It was also before ST:Generations was made. I know it is not the novel Star Trek: Federation, as the two crews actually work together and meet one another. Also, I seem to remember that the front cover said something to the effect of, "at last, the generations meet!"

Answer (score 8):

How about [Star Trek: Crossover](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Crossover_%28novel%29)?

Comment: Yep, that's the one I think @matt is talking about.  And it's on my bookshelf right now. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The novel I'm thinking of has the TOS-era timeline, including TOS-era Kirk. I thought it might be "Crossover" but that's in the TNG-era, without Kirk. I remember there being a timewarp-like plot involved (much like TNG's "Yesterday's Enterprise"). I also remember there being a scene when the two crews meet one another. Worf says something to the effect of, "Captain, it's the Enterprise NCC-1701, and she's hailing us." Man, trying to find this novel has been an issue for years! :)

Comment: @Matt there's a reasonably complete list of offical TOS era books at http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series#Prose

Comment: Did this novel involve Tribbles?

Comment: I'm not sure if tribbles are in it or not. I've never read the book. I do remember being in a shop one day and reading the description. This was about 20 years ago when TNG was in the height of its popularity. I don't believe ST: Generations was out yet, because I remember thinking to myself while reading the description, "Wow! I hope they make a movie someday where the crews meet!"

I didn't have enough money at the time, so I couldn't buy it. But I do remember reading a couple key scenes. Too bad I don't remember the author or title.

Answer (score 3):

"At last, the generations meet" appears on the cover of the book, [Unification](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unification_(novel))

[image]

This is a novelization of the two-part TNG episode with the same name.  I think that the only TOS character who appears, though, is Spock.

It was released in 1991.

Comment: I just realized how old the question was....it was recently active :-)   I hope it is still of some use....

Answer (score 2):

Federation.

Published in 1994. I bought it at a Waldenbooks in a mall near Groton, CT when I was 18. I was right out of boot camp

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_(novel)

[image]

Comment: "*I know it is not the novel Star Trek: Federation*"

Comment: Other than the plot involves a TOS and TNG meet/crossover having to work together with there being a timewarp like plot and in the novel there is the exact quote mentioned in the description being looked for, there’s no way it could be Federation. Except that it is.

Comment: If you're going to contradict OP explicitly stating that this isn't the right answer, you need to explain (in your answer, not in comments) **why you think you're right and they're wrong**

Comment: “I was right out of boot camp” — Boothby's advice still ringing in your ears.

Comment: while not the answer - "Federation" is a great book - the book that 'Generations' should have been (but I don't hate Generations)